# Jquery :not to order some records on a table

Tags: jquery

Im ordering some records on a table using jquery:

```
$('#SubscribersManageList tr:contains("tel:"):not(:has(img[src*="images/plus.gif"]))').css("background-color", "#B1F299").insertAfter("tr.Heading3:last");
$('#SubscribersManageList tr:contains("$"):not(:has(img[src*="images/plus.gif"]))').css("background-color", "#FFC").insertAfter("tr.Heading3:last");
```

There is no problem with the above, now the problem is when im trying to use this as the third line:

```
$('#SubscribersManageList tr:not("$,tel:"):not(:has(img[src*="images/plus.gif"]))').insertAfter("tr.Heading3:last");
```

What im trying to express on the third line is: if the tr doesnt contain "$" or "tel:" and it doesnt contain images/plus.gif then insert it  there.

This third line is not working, why?

UPDATE: i used this but still not working

```
$('#SubscribersManageList tr:not(:contains("$"),:contains("tel:")):not(:has(img[src*="images/plus.gif"]))').insertAfter("tr.Heading3:last");
```

ok i figured out its actually selecting what i want BUT its not doing the .insertAfter("tr.Heading3:last")  why?

http://jsfiddle.net/Zk28s/1/    if u want to try to add the third line

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `:not(:contains("$"),:contains("tel:")` instead of `:not("$,tel:")`?

PS. That's a *huge* selector. It might be nicer if you were to split it up using `.filter`, `.not` and friends (not to mention easier to debug).

Comment: sorry it didnt work, i used this:

    $('#SubscribersManageList tr:not(:contains("$"),:contains("tel:")):not(:has(img[src*="images/plus.gif"]))').insertAfter("tr.Heading3:last");

Comment: ok i figured out its actually selecting what i want BUT its not doing the .insertAfter("tr.Heading3:last")  why?

Comment: Yes please paste the line i sent u on the javascript part so u see what happens when u execute it: http://jsfiddle.net/Zk28s/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, there was some error in your not selector for contains.

```
$("tr.Heading3:last").after($('#SubscribersManageList tr:not(:contains("$")):not(:contains("tel:")):not(:has(img[src*="images/plus.gif"]))'));
```

Comment: any suggestion? its selecting them OK but its not inserting them at the top like the rest.